# Can you make a form with a single HTML file?

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit, weebly

All of the examples of making drop-down forms that I can find involve having a separate PHP file.  I'm trying to embed some code into a Weebly page, so I'm not sure that I can save a separate PHP file on the server.  So is it possible to avoid PHP entirely?  Maybe do everything in JavaScript and jQuery?  Or to put the form and the PHP in the same HTML file?

More specifically what I'm trying to do is make a page where there are several drop-down forms.  The user selects several options, clicks submit, the client-side back-end does some computation on the inputs, and prints out a result.

I've been trying to follow this guide for dropdowns: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

And I've been following this for using PHP in forms: https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/

With that guidance I created this non-working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  $Level = $_POST["level"];
?>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
      Choose a level: <select name="level" id="level">
        <option value="high">High</option>
        <option value="med">Medium</option>
        <option value="low">Low</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <p>
    <?php
      echo "".$Level;
    ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I say that it's not working because when I click on anything in the drop-down, nothing happens.

---

This further information came from an exchange in the comments:

Ah, this really doesn't need to interact with the server. It's ultimately just going to be a tool so that customers can get an automatically generated estimated quote on a price. So they answer some questions (i.e. select some drop-downs and enter some numbers in fields) and click submit, and the web page spits out an estimate. No information saved or anything like that, so it should be fine to handle everything client-side. From your description, though, it sounds like that can't be done with PHP then. I don't think Weebly will let me change the file extension.

Comment: What's "the client-side back-end"?  Do you mean that you want to perform all of the logic in JavaScript, essentially not submitting a form at all?

Comment: @David What I mean by that is that it's client-side, and it's some logical computation which is not shown to the user.  So it's just "back-end" in the sense that it's the logic, and the user only gets to see the output.  I guess in a sense it's not submitting a form since the information doesn't have to leave.  I guess it's more like a "compute" than a "submit" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. You can use the `onSubmit` attribute on your form to run some javascript (and by extension jquery) without actually submitting the form. More specifically, it would look something like this:

```
<form onSubmit="return yourJavascriptFunction()" method="post">
```

Inside your script, you can get the dropdown values from the form's fields using `document.getElementById(yourDropdownID)` and perform any necessary actions. If you don't want your form to redirect, just `return false;` on your function. Using this method, you don't really need a form, and can use some `<select>` tags with id, as well as a pseudo submit button:

```
<button onclick="yourFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this with php you have to change the extension as php and add a submit button otherwise you can do this without php easly like below.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
      Choose a level: <select name="level" id="level" onChange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = this.value;">
        <option value="high">High</option>
        <option value="med">Medium</option>
        <option value="low">Low</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <p> <span id="selectedValue"></span></p>
```

Answer (score -4):

remove the DOCTYPE html and change the extension of your file to .php

Comment: Please edit your answer, do not post corrections as comments :)

Comment: I don't think I can change the file extension since this is done on Weebly.